# PHP - Does require_once launches the __construct method of the required Class

Tags: php

I am learning PHP and trying to build my own framework on my own, I will have a front controller approach (index.php) and I was wondering if when I require my files (in my case different classes like Globals.php, BaseController.php) the construct methods of my classe will execute when required.

Index.php

```html
<?php
//1 - Includes global variables
require_once 'config/Globals.php';
 
//2 - Includes Base Controller
require_once 'core/ControladorBase.php';
 
//Front Controller functions
require_once 'core/ControladorFrontal.func.php';
 
//Launch actions through controllers
if(isset($_GET["controller"])){
    $controllerObj=loadController($_GET["controller"]);
    launchAction($controllerObj);
}else{
    $controllerObj=loadController(default_controller);
    launchAction($controllerObj);
}
?>
```

BaseController

```html
<?php
class BaseController{
 
    public function __construct() {
        require_once 'Connect.php';
        require_once 'BaseEntity.php';
         
        //Include all models
        foreach(glob("model/*.php") as $file){
            require_once $file;
        }
    }
     
    //Plugins and functionalities
     
    public function view($view,$data){
        foreach ($data as $assoc_id => $value) {
            ${$assoc_id}=$value; 
        }
         
        require_once 'core/ViewsHelper.php';
        $helper=new ViewsHelper();
     
        require_once 'view/'.$view.'View.php';
    }
     
    public function redirect($controller=default_controller,$action=default_action){
        header("Location:index.php?controller=".$controller."&action=".$action);
    }
     
    //Methods for the controllers
 
}
?>
```

Comment: I'd recommend that you go read a little about autoload

Comment: No, the constructor is called when instantiated, `new BaseController`.

Comment: Wow, you have too many open questions. Time to clean house and accept some answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.

When you run `require_once`, PHP will simply add this file to your current code, allowing you to access classes/variables inside those files. But the `__construct()` method only executes when you create a new instance of a class, like `$user = new User();`.